# How to set local function definition using function (or closure) objects?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

The problem with `flet` is that the functions bound therein must be defined inline. In other words, there's no way to do this:

```
(new-flet ((a (lambda (f x)
                (funcall f (* x 2))))
           (b (function-generator)))
    (a #'b 10))
```

I considered defining such a macro myself, but the problem is that `flet` seems to be the *only* way to set local function values. `symbol-function` always gets the global definition only, and `function` can't be used with `setf`. Anyone have an idea how this can be done fairly cleanly, if at all?

Comment: I think you are forgetting about `labels`.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about `labels`. My questions doesn't have anything to do with mutually recursive function bindings. The same problem here applies to `flet` and `labels`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just too used to Scheme I guess.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Do you want to be able to override function calls inside of a function outside that function scope without using flet? Is Let and funcall what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily build a trampoline

```
(defun function-generator (x)
  (lambda (y) (* x y)))

(let ((fg (function-generator 42)))
  (flet ((a (f x) (funcall f (* x 2)))
         (b (x) (funcall fg x)))
    (a #'b 10)))
```

A macro implementation of `new-flet` with this approach is

```
(defmacro new-flet (bindings &body body)
  (let ((let-bindings (list))
        (flet-bindings (list))
        (args (gensym)))
    (dolist (binding bindings)
      (let ((name (gensym)))
        (push `(,name ,(second binding))
              let-bindings)
        (push `(,(first binding) (&rest ,args)
                 (apply ,name ,args))
              flet-bindings)))
    `(let ,(nreverse let-bindings)
       (flet ,(nreverse flet-bindings)
         ,@body))))
```

that expands in your example case as

```
(macroexpand-1 '(new-flet ((a (lambda (f x) (funcall f (* x 2))))
                           (b (function-generator)))
                  (a #'b 10)))

==> (LET ((#:G605 (LAMBDA (F X)
                    (FUNCALL F (* X 2))))
          (#:G606 (FUNCTION-GENERATOR)))
      (FLET ((A (&REST #:G604)
               (APPLY #:G605 #:G604))
             (B (&REST #:G604)
               (APPLY #:G606 #:G604)))
        (A #'B 10)))
```

Comment: `MAKE-sYMBOL` might be preferable. Depends. Also here one might also declare `dynamic-extent` for the new `&rest` variable. Lisp might be able to exploit that.

Comment: Awesome. I was afraid this would be impossible because I thought the macro would have to transform every instance of `(a ...)` into `(funcall a ...)` (which wouldn't work cleanly when, e.g., `(a ...)` is itself part of another special syntactical form to be transformed later). I didn't think to just wrap the function in another.

Comment: @RainerJoswig What are the advantages/disadvantages to using `make-symbol` vs. `gensym`?

Answer (score 1):

Is

```
(let* ((a (lambda (f x) (funcall f (* x 2))))
       (b (function-generator)))
    (funcall a b 10))
```

a fairly clean solution to your problem?

Comment: Obviously, that's not the same as `flet`, which binds the given identifiers in the function namespace. :-(

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young No, it is not the same as `flet`, but it _is_ a minor rewrite that makes the code in the question work. Thus the question if it could be regarded as a _fairly clean_ solution.

Comment: Your solution is actually a macro-expansion of the solution I was looking for. I didn't want to have to write `funcall` all over the place--just once, in the macro definition.

Answer (score 1):

How about binding the variables with `let`, so that they're `setf`able, and then using an `flet` as the body of the `let` so that they're `funcall`able and `(function …)`-able, too.  E.g., where I've given a silly little function instead of `(generate-function)`:

```
(let ((a (lambda (f x)
           (funcall f (* x 2))))
      (b (lambda (&rest args)
           (print (list* 'print-from-b args)))))
  (flet ((a (&rest args)
           (apply a args))
         (b (&rest args)
           (apply b args)))
    (a #'b 10)))
```

We can wrap this up in a macro relatively easily:

```
(defmacro let/flet (bindings &body body)
  (let ((args (gensym (string '#:args-))))
    `(let ,bindings
       (flet ,(loop :for (name nil) :in bindings
                 :collect `(,name (&rest ,args) (apply ,name ,args)))
         ,@body))))
```

Now

```
(let/flet ((a (lambda (f x)
                (funcall f (* x 2))))
           (b (lambda (&rest args)
                (print (list* 'print-from-b args)))))
  (a #'b 10))
```

expands into the first block of code.  Note that you can also use `(a b 10)` in the body as well, since the binding of `b` is the same as the value of `#'b`. You can use `setf` on the variable as well:

```
(let/flet ((a (lambda (x)
                (print (list 'from-a x)))))
  (a 23)
  (setf a (lambda (x)
            (print (list 'from-new-a x x))))
  (a 23))
```

prints

```
(FROM-A 23) 
(FROM-NEW-A 23 23)
```

Comment: The let/flet combination here is the same as the one in [6502's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18363025/1281433) (which I didn't read carefully enough before writing this one), except that here the variable bindings are preserved, so that `setf` works on them, which was one of the requirements in the question.  I think that the macro code is a bit easier to read, too.

Comment: This is good, but I think 6502's answer is slightly better, since his doesn't pollute the variable namespace. Nice work nonetheless.

Comment: @nbtrap Does that mean you don't need to be able to `setf` the functions after all?

Comment: Being able to setf the _local function slot_ would have enabled me to write a clean macro that I was envisioning (without messing with the variable namespace). But the solution you and 6502 provided make that unnecessary. I was thinking too shallowly.

Comment: @nbtrap Ah, then yes, 6502's is nice for not polluting the variable namespace.  I'll leave this here in case someone _does_ want to be able to update the bindings (and, while it may just be personal taste, I still think this macro code (which can be easily modified not to pollute the value namespace) is a bit easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested in a `labels` equivalent, here it is:

```
(defmacro my-labels ((&rest definitions) &rest body)
  (let ((gensyms (loop for d in definitions collect (gensym)))
        (names (loop for d in definitions collect (car d)))
        (fdefs (loop for f in definitions collect (cadr f)))
        (args (gensym)))
    `(let (,@(loop for g in gensyms collect (list g)))
       (labels (,@(loop for g in gensyms for n in names
                     collect `(,n (&rest ,args) (apply ,g ,args))))
         ,@(loop for g in gensyms for f in fdefs
                collect `(setf ,g ,f))
         ,@body))))
```

This is sort of like Scheme's `letrec`.